# Training by party keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression, image-segmentation, training-data

I need your help.
my project in general is about the development of an image analysis algorithm for the quantification of ferritin in sclera.
My code allows to mix segmentation and regression with the sequential model and the output is unique (i.e. the training is done at the same time). I want it to be per part. i.e., it does the segmentation training, it records the result and starts the regression one.

- the inputs of the segmentation are the images plus their masks;
- the inputs of the regressions are the images plus the values of ferritins.

## Segmentation and regression layers are renamed

## because some of them share the same name when backbones are used

def load_model(segmentation_model, regression_model, width, height, num_classes = 1):

```
# Rename segmentation model layers and weights
for layer in segmentation_model.layers:
    rename(segmentation_model, layer, layer.name + '_seg')
#for i, w in enumerate(segmentation_model.weights):
#    split_name = w.name.split('/')
#    new_name = split_name[0] + '_seg' + '/' + split_name[1]
#    segmentation_model.weights[i]._handle_name = new_name

# Rename regression model layers
for layer in regression_model.layers:
    rename(regression_model, layer, layer.name + '_reg')
#for i, w in enumerate(regression_model.weights):
#    split_name = w.name.split('/')
#    new_name = split_name[0] + '_reg' + '/' + split_name[1]
#    regression_model.weights[i]._handle_name = new_name

image = layers.Input(shape=(width, height, 3), name="img")

mask_image = segmentation_model(image)

if num_classes==1:
    mask_image_categorical = K.cast(K.squeeze(mask_image, axis=3) + 0.5, dtype='int32') # Threshold at 0.5
else:
    mask_image_categorical = K.argmax(mask_image, axis=3)

masked_layer = mylayers.CustomMasking(mask_value=0)
masked_image = masked_layer.call([image, mask_image_categorical])

value = regression_model(masked_image)

m = models.Model(inputs=image, outputs=[mask_image, value])
#m = models.Model(inputs=image, outputs=[mask_image, value, mask_image_categorical, masked_image])

#for i, w in enumerate(m.weights): print(i, w.name)

m.summary()

return m
```

def make_train(model, regression_loss_weight, regression_loss_weight_max, train_generator, epochs, val_dataset, validation_steps, weights_path, logger_path, num_classes, focal, enable_plot, init_mode = False):

```
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

regression_loss_weight_variable = K.variable(regression_loss_weight, name='regression_loss_weight')
mse = losses.MeanSquaredError()
weighted_mse = weighted_loss(mse, regression_loss_weight_variable)
weighted_mse.trainable = False

if focal:
    if num_classes == 1:
        bce = mylosses.binary_focal_loss
        weighted_bce = weighted_loss(bce, 1 - regression_loss_weight_variable)
        loss = { 'model_segmentation' : weighted_bce, 'model_regression' : weighted_mse} 
    else:
        fce = mylosses.categorical_focal_loss
        weighted_fce = weighted_loss(fce, 1 - regression_loss_weight_variable)
        loss = { 'model_segmentation' : weighted_fce, 'model_regression' : weighted_mse}
else:
    if num_classes == 1:
        bce = losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        weighted_bce = weighted_loss(bce, 1 - regression_loss_weight_variable)
        loss = { 'model_segmentation' : weighted_bce, 'model_regression' : weighted_mse}
    else:
        cce = losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
        weighted_cce = weighted_loss(cce, 1 - regression_loss_weight_variable)
        loss = { 'model_segmentation' : weighted_cce, 'model_regression' : weighted_mse} 

metric = metrics.BinaryAccuracy() if num_classes == 1 else metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
metric_array_segmentation = [metric, mymetrics.iou_score_threshold, mymetrics.f1_score_threshold]
metric_array_regression = [metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(), metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(), metrics.MeanAbsolutePercentageError()]
metric_dict = { 'model_segmentation' : metric_array_segmentation, 'model_regression' : metric_array_regression}

loss_weights = [1.0, 1.0] # Weight for regression is taken into account in weighted_mse loss function

model.compile(optimizer, loss, metric_dict, loss_weights)

loss_weight_callback = LossWeightsCallback(regression_loss_weight_variable, regression_loss_weight, regression_loss_weight_max, epochs, 'val_model_segmentation_f1-score')
freezing_callback = SegmentationModelFreezingCallback(model, 'val_model_segmentation_f1-score', 0.95)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weights_path, monitor='val_model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
csv_logger = CSVLogger(logger_path, append=True, separator=';')
lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', mode='min', factor=0.2, patience=10, min_lr=10e-7, min_delta=0.01, verbose=1)
earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20, restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks_list = [loss_weight_callback, freezing_callback, checkpoint, csv_logger, lr_reducer, earlystopping]

# Test custom masking layer or global model
#instance = train_generator[0]
#imgs = np.squeeze(instance[0], axis=3) if instance[0].shape[3] == 1 else instance[0]
#imsave("unmasked_img.png", imgs[0])
#masks = np.squeeze(instance[1]['model_segmentation'], axis=3) if instance[1]['model_segmentation'].shape[3] == 1 else instance[1]['model_segmentation']
#imsave("mask.png", masks[0] * 255)
#masked_layer = mylayers.CustomMasking(mask_value=0)
#masked_imgs = masked_layer.call([imgs, masks])
#img = K.eval(masked_imgs[0,:,:,:])
#imsave("masked_img.png", img)
#y = model(imgs)
#mask_image = y[0][0,:,:,:]
#value = K.eval(y[1][0])

if init_mode:
    instance = train_generator[0]
    model.train_on_batch(instance[0][:1], [instance[1]['model_segmentation'][:1], instance[1]['model_regression'][:1]] )
else:
    results = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_dataset, validation_steps=validation_steps, callbacks=callbacks_list)
    model.save_weights(weights_path)

# Display of metrics and loss vs epochs: metric names must match the metric functions
if enable_plot:
    if num_classes == 1:
        plot_history(results, 
            metrics = ['model_segmentation_binary_accuracy', 'val_model_segmentation_binary_accuracy', 'model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', 'val_model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', 'model_regression_mean_absolute_error', 'val_model_regression_mean_absolute_error', 'model_regression_mean_absolute_percentage_error', 'val_model_regression_mean_absolute_percentage_error'], 
            losses = ['model_segmentation_loss', 'model_regression_loss', 'val_model_segmentation_loss', 'val_model_regression_loss'])
    else:
        plot_history(results, 
            metrics = ['model_segmentation_categorical_accuracy', 'val_model_segmentation_categorical_accuracy', 'model_segmentation_mean_io_u', 'val_model_segmentation_mean_io_u', 'model_segmentation_f1-score', 'val_model_segmentation_f1-score', 'model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', 'val_model_regression_root_mean_squared_error', 'model_regression_mean_absolute_error', 'val_model_regression_mean_absolute_error', 'model_regression_mean_absolute_percentage_error', 'val_model_regression_mean_absolute_percentage_error'], 
            losses = ['model_segmentation_loss', 'model_regression_loss', 'val_model_segmentation_loss', 'val_model_regression_loss'])
```

## Defining model and loading weights is not enough when using custom model and/or layer

## Model must also be compiled and trained on a minimal set in order to initialize

def init_model(model, loss_weight, loss_weight_max, train_generator, epochs, weights_path, logger_path, num_classes, focal):

```
make_train(model, loss_weight, loss_weight_max, train_generator, epochs, None, None, '', logger_path, num_classes, focal, False, True)
model.load_weights(weights_path)
```